# Recursive subtraction in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, scipy

Consider the following recursive problem: Say I have `total_units` of something that I can spend in `total_days`.  On any given day, as I spend these units, I have `units_left` units and `days_left` left. Based on this, I can define the `ideal_daily_rate` as `units_left/days_left`.

Now, let's assume that, **starting from day one**, we choose to spend at `20%` above the `ideal_daily_rate` **every day**. Note that, at the beginning of any given day, `ideal_daily_rate` is **always** calculated as `units_left/days_left`, we are just choosing to spend 20% more of the `ideal__daily_rate` on that particular day.

The goal is to obtain how many units I spend every day given the initial conditions `total_units`, `total_days` and the above-ideal-rate `20%`.

Is there a library in `numpy` that can help handle / vectorize this type of recursion?

Comment: It seems like a straightforward 10-line simulation to me. Why would you need a library? It is a difference equation without lags... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this needs recursion. Here is a short simulation to get the values you are describing. It is essentially a decay difference equation (a discrete version of a differential equation). Correct me if you think I have misunderstood something.

```
days_left = 100
units_left = 50
ideal_daily_rate = units_left/days_left
spend = 1.2*ideal_daily_rate

while (days_left>0):
    print( "days_left: %4.1f unit_left: %4.1f ideal: %5.2f spend: %5.2f" % (days_left,units_left,ideal_daily_rate,spend))
    units_left -= spend
    days_left -= 1
    if (days_left>0):
        ideal_daily_rate = units_left/days_left
        spend = 1.2*ideal_daily_rate
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `i = number of units` and `N = total number of days`. The number of units left after succeeding days is,

```
i1 = i0*(1-1.2/N)
i2 = i1*(1-1.2/(N-1)) = i0*(1-1.2/N)*(1-1.2/(N-1))
etc.
```

You can calculate this in numpy using:

```
i = np.cumprod(1-1.2/np.arange(1,N+1)[::-1])*i0
```

Comment: I like this solution, but you can't spend 20% more than the ideal number of units on the last day because you won't have enough units left to spend (`i[9] = -1.09730284`)

Comment: @xnx,  yeah you could do something like `i[i < 0] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way

```
def tock(days,units,perc_more):

    loop = reversed(xrange(days+1)) #a little fanciness... 
                                    #probably not the best method

    for day in loop:
        if day == 0: break
        ideal_rate = units/day
        spend = ideal_rate * perc_more
        print(spend)
        units = units - spend

%timeit -n 10 tock(10,10,1.2)
```